# Casting boost::units::quantity to double

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I need to pass the value of a quantity to a library for evaluation.  The [boost units library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) takes double values in SI, so the boost units library is very appealing in ensuring that requirement.  However, how should I cast the quantity to a double value?  The documentation and example seems to avoid this since the intent is to, rightfully so, maintain the units.

Something like:

```
quantity<pressure> p(101.1 * kilo * pascals);
double dblP = static_cast<double>(p);  // double value in Pascals
```

Going through the headers suggests...  Is that the correct way to cast to the base type?

```
p.value();
```

Comment: "Going through the headers suggests... `p.value()`" So your question is?

Comment: Good point - sorry I added that after the question was first asked.  What I want to ensure is .value() does return what I expect reliably.  Ie, is it after any needed conversions such as psi to Pa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [reference documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/units/quantity_BOOST_U_id1897170.html#id1897251-bb) shows that either implicit casts or the `value()` member method can be used.

> 1. `operator value_type() const;`
>
>    implicit conversion to value_type is allowed
> 2. `const value_type & value() const;`
>
>    constant accessor to value

Comment: Thank you, that reference is very helpful (and hard to find with keywords quantity unit boost cast)

Comment: `operator value_type() const;` only exists for dimensionless quantites. Otherwise this would be possible: `double v = quantity<si::length>()`.

Answer (score 9):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
quantity<pressure> p(101.1 * kilo * pascals);
double dblP = p / pascals;  // double value in Pascals
```

If you divide out the unit, you are left with a `quantity<dimensionless>` which will implicitly convert to a `double`. This eliminates any question of what the internal representation (which `value()` returns) units are.

Answer (score 7):

Just spotted this.  I think the intended method is to use Boost's `quantity_cast` operator.

```
quantity<pressure> p(101.1 * kilo * pascals);
double dblP = quantity_cast<double>(p);
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_units/Quantities.html#boost_units.Quantities.Quantity_Construction_and_Conversion