# Mixed units with boost::units

Tags: c++, boost-units

In my program, I would like to take advantage of boost::units for type safe computations and automatic conversions. As a novice user of the library, I have a basic understanding of how it works, and why implicit type conversion is [forbidden](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_units/Quantities.html#boost_units.Quantities.Quantity_Construction_and_Conversion).

Right now I can write code like this

```
using namespace boost::units;
using namespace boost::units::si;

quantity<mass> my_mass(50 * kilogram);
quantity<force> my_force = my_mass * 9.81 * meter / pow<2>(second);
```

Where `my_mass` will be expressed in kilograms and `my_force` in Newton. But for convenience when interacting with other libraries which accept only `double`, I would prefer forces to be in kiloNewton (and, similarly, pressures in MegaPascal). So I do this:

```
typedef make_scaled_unit<force, scale<10, static_rational<3>>>::type kiloforce;
quantity<kiloforce> scaled_force(my_mass * 9.81 * meter / pow<2>(second));
```

Which works, but forces an explicit conversion. The following code, rightfully, does not compile:

```
quantity<kiloforce> scaled_force = my_mass * 9.81 * meter / pow<2>(second);
```

Because it represents an implicit conversion. My question is then: is there a way to configure the library so that quantities are expressed in the scaled unit of choice?

After all, this is the case for "kilogram", so I looked into [scaled units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_units/Units.html#boost_units.Units.scaled_units), but I cannot seem to find a way to make it work. The idea would have been to define a custom system, but since mass, force and pressure are related to each other, this is not possible, as explained [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/units/make_system.hpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem seems to be that you're looking for a dimensionless force in kilonewtons. That's [not hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937004/casting-boostunitsquantity-to-double) :

```
quantity<force> my_force = my_mass * 9.81 * meter / pow<2>(second);
double F = my_force / (kilo*newtons); // my_force in kN
```

The physics problem seems to be "kiloforce". That's not how physics works. Forces do not have prefixes, units do. E.g. length vs. meter/kilometer and mass vs gram/kilogram. Similarly, force vs Nnewton/kiloNewton.

That said, may I suggest

```
make_scaled_unit<acceleration, scale<10, static_rational<3>>>::type g(0.00981);
```

Don't ask me why you'd express the earth's acceleration in kilometers per second squared, but a kiloNewton *is* a kilometer kilogram per second squared.

Comment: Conversions like the one you suggest (pretty sleek, though) or `quantity<kiloforce>(my_force).value()` are what I am trying to avoid. Having `g` expressed in `km * kg / s2` feels a bit hacky... it will probably interfere with other calculations not involving forces.

Comment: Accepting the answer as it explains that "it cannot be done the way I asked", which after some time I realize is correct.